# Problem with Liquibase sql file with runOnChange:true Version 3.8

Tags: version, liquibase

I try to execute a stored procedure on every liquibase update, but 'am not able to accomplish this.

The first line of the sql Script containes the following information:;

```
--changeset test:1.122.-plsql endDelimiter:"\n/" runOnChange:true validCheckSum:any runAlways:true runOrder:first
```

But on a second run this script is not executed. 
Any Idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple, I overlooked to add the liquibase line
--liquibase formatted sql

So Issue is solved